# Axios download file with original right extension

Tags: vue.js, download, axios, blob, vuex

I have below vuex method for download file :

```
   downloadFile(context, url) {
      return new promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const method = "GET";
        axios
          .request({
            url: url,
            method,
            responseType: "blob"
          })
          .then(response => {
            let fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(
              new Blob([response.data]),
              {
                type: response.headers["content-type"]
              }
            );
            let fileLink = document.createElement("a");
            fileLink.href = fileURL;
            let fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"].split(
              "filename="
            )[1];
         
            fileLink.setAttribute("download", fileName);
            document.body.appendChild(fileLink);

            fileLink.click();
            fileLink.remove();
            resolve();
          })
          .catch(() => {
            reject();
          });
      });
    }
```

I pass the URL link (getting from laravel API)

> Blockquote

**the problem that the file always downloaded with txt extension**

> Blockquote

**There is any method to get the file extension?**
[image]

Comment: Your server didn't send the file extension in the screenshot.  So you can either 1) Fix your server response to include the extension, or 2) Deduce the extension from the `Content-Type`

Comment: Is the extension in the `url` passed to `downloadFile`?  If so, you can just take it from there too.

Comment: No it not contain the extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server didn't send the file extension in the screenshot. If it's not in `downloadFile`'s `url` argument and you can't fix your server response to include it, you could deduce it from `Content-Type`. You could create a hash linking each content type to an extension.

Remove this:

```js
let fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"].split(
   "filename="
)[1];
```

Replace it with this to capture the extension:

```js
const extensions = {
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document': 'docx',
  'application/fake': 'fake', // Just an example
  // etc. Add another line for every Content-Type
}
const contentType = response.headers["Content-Type"];
const extension = extensions[contentType];
const filename = 'file.' + extension;
```

This will name every file *"file.<extension>"*

Comment: Is there a way to define all extension types in the const variable?
@Dan

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint does not supply the extension you can add it in the `fileName`. So it could be:

```
-  fileLink.setAttribute("download", fileName);
+  const extention = 'pdf'; // example
+  fileLink.setAttribute("download", `${fileName}.${extention}`);
```

Comment: I have multiple types
I need it to be dynamic
@Adam Orlov

Comment: If backend won't give you the information about the file type, somehow you need to figure out what extention to use on your own. Maybe based on some `header` ?. I have showed you how you can save the file with different extention, which is what you asked for .

Comment: Thank you dear,but i need to know how i can get the file extension

Comment: Does `Content-Type` header change when getting different files? Maybe based on this header you can figure it out.